# Get a coverage of linux program without recompiling it

Tags: linux, code-coverage, valgrind

Is it possible to get source coverage (just like it done by gcov) of program, compiled without `-pg` (FIX, not a -pg really, but `fprofile-arcs` and `ftest-coverage`, sorry)? I want to get this without recompiling, e.g. with valgrind, which can instrument programm at runtime. I can afford a very slow execution (up to 1000x slowdown).

What I need is a flag for each source code line: "Was this line executed or not". I need exact coverage (not a profiling) and for every line (not for functions).

Comment: Why can't it be recompiled with `-g`?  If it is in production, there is no reason why a sandbox can't have it recompiled, hooking up simulated input, and then profiling....

Comment: wallyk, `-pg` and `-g` are different options. Recompiling of this project is very slow and hard. But I want to cover only some parts of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems yes: http://benjamin-meyer.blogspot.com/2007/12/valgrind-callgrind-tools-part-3-code.html using a third-party [callgrind_tools](https://github.com/icefox/callgrind_tools):

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard way of doing this. Its theoretically possible, but I'm not aware of any tools that help you do this.

Comment: but valgrind is able to recompile a programme dynamically... So it can instrument it just like `-pg` did.

Comment: Also, qemu with user-space (application level) emulation can collect coverage information.